# How to update a key in a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap, key

I can't find any method which allows me to update the key of a `HashMap`. There is [`get_key_value`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_key_value), but it returns an immutable reference and not a mutable reference.

Comment: You can't, you'd have to remove and insert it. What are you trying to do? Maybe there's something else you could be doing.

Answer (score 10):

You *generally*<sup>1</sup> cannot. From the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) documentation:

> It is a logic error for a key to be modified in such a way that the key's hash, as determined by the `Hash` trait, or its equality, as determined by the `Eq` trait, changes while it is in the map. This is normally only possible through `Cell`, `RefCell`, global state, I/O, or unsafe code.

Instead, remove the value and re-insert it:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

fn rename_key<K, V>(h: &mut HashMap<K, V>, old_key: &K, new_key: K)
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    if let Some(v) = h.remove(old_key) {
        h.insert(new_key, v);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Changing key of HashMap from child method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37097489/155423)

---

**1** — As the documentation states, it's *possible* to modify it, so long as you don't change how the key is hashed or compared. Doing so will cause the `HashMap` to be in an invalid state.

An example of doing it correctly (but it's still dubious *why*):

```rust
use std::{
    cell::RefCell,
    collections::HashMap,
    hash::{Hash, Hasher},
    sync::Arc,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Example<A, B>(A, B);

impl<A, B> PartialEq for Example<A, B>
where
    A: PartialEq,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0 == other.0
    }
}

impl<A, B> Eq for Example<A, B> where A: Eq {}

impl<A, B> Hash for Example<A, B>
where
    A: Hash,
{
    fn hash<H>(&self, h: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher,
    {
        self.0.hash(h)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    let key = Arc::new(Example(0, RefCell::new(false)));

    h.insert(key.clone(), "alpha");
    dbg!(&h);

    *key.1.borrow_mut() = true;
    dbg!(&h);
}
```

There are other techniques you can use to get a mutable reference to the key, such as the unstable [`raw_entry_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut) (as [mentioned by Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580524/how-to-update-a-key-in-a-hashmap/65580623?noredirect=1#comment115950316_65580623)).

Comment: There's also the unstable `raw_entry_mut()` method which will give mutable access to keys once stabilized, but of course you can still only make changes that don't modify a key's hash, nor how it compares to other keys.